# Android drawArc irregular arc

Tags: android, canvas, draw

[Illustration](http://imageshack.com/a/img538/4559/7YkH2h.png)

I am drawing multiple segments of an arc using the same RectF, however the arcs do not line up properly. I tried all CAP Options, but it never looks symmetrical.

```
 private void initPaint(TypedArray a){

    segmentInactivePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    segmentInactivePaint.setColor(a.getColor(R.styleable.SegmentsCustomView_segmentBgColor, segmentBgColor));
    segmentInactivePaint.setStrokeWidth(30f);
    segmentInactivePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

    segmentsBGPaint = new Paint(segmentInactivePaint);
    segmentsBGPaint.setAlpha(64);

    segmentActivePaint = new Paint(segmentInactivePaint);
    segmentActivePaint.setColor(a.getColor(R.styleable.SegmentsCustomView_segmentActiveColor,segmentActiveColor));

}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    if(getWidth()<getHeight()) {
        rectF.set(getLeft(), getTop(), getWidth() - getLeft(), getWidth() - getLeft());
    }else{
        rectF.set(getLeft(), getTop(), getHeight() - getTop(), getHeight() - getTop());

    }
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    position = 0;
    for(int i=0; i < segmentSizes.length; i++){
        canvas.drawArc(rectF,position-180,segmentSizes[i]-segmentGap,false,
                i != segmentActive ?
                            i < segmentActive ? segmentInactivePaint :  segmentsBGPaint
                        : segmentActivePaint);
        position+=segmentSizes[i];
    }

}
```

I also tried using a static RectF, that is not changed by any resizing events, so that is not the problem.

```
RectF (0):﹕ [75.0,75.0][759.0,759.0]
RectF (1):﹕ [75.0,75.0][759.0,759.0]
RectF (2):﹕ [75.0,75.0][759.0,759.0]
RectF (3):﹕ [75.0,75.0][759.0,759.0]
RectF (4):﹕ [75.0,75.0][759.0,759.0]
```

My guess would be, that the Canvas.drawArc method creates a partial path and therefore the interpolation of the arc always differs from the arc of a full circle.

A push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to fix the problem by using a Path instead of the drawArc() method of the canvas. By rewinding the path whenever I am drawing a new segment.

```
 @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        position = 0;
        for(int i=0; i < segmentSizes.length; i++){
            if(i == segmentActive){
                tmpPaint = segmentActivePaint;
            }else if(i > segmentActive){
                tmpPaint = segmentsBGPaint;
            }else{
                tmpPaint = segmentInactivePaint;
            }

            path.rewind();
            path.addArc(rectF,position - 180, segmentSizes[i] - segmentGap);
            canvas.drawPath(path, tmpPaint);
            position+=segmentSizes[i];
        }
        path.reset();

    }
```

The rewinding seems to manage to draw a nearly perfect circle regardless of the number of sub-arcs.

The drawArc() method seems to work fairly similar to addArc(), however it resets the path on every call.